# Unexpected results when searching surrounding squares in Conway's Game of Life

Tags: c#

I'm trying to recreate Conway's Game of Life from scratch in C# so I can improve my programming skills but when I run it I get some really strange and unexpected results.

I've hardcoded the first board to be:

▢ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ 
▢ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ■ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢

it should then get calculated as:

▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
■ ■ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ■ ▢ ▢ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ■ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ■ ■ ▢
▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢ ▢

Then repeat and infinitely oscillate between the two states. When running the code, it doesn't seem to happen as expected, each generation random squares that shouldn't be on turn on and it appears to count the surrounding squares incorrectly. I think it's got something to do with the alive() function but I can't seem to find any issues with it.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Game_of_Life
{
    class Game_Of_Life
    {
        private static readonly int[] dimensions = { 10, 10 };
        private static readonly int[,] initBoard = new int[,]

           {{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};

        private int[,] oldBoard = initBoard;
        private int[,] newBoard = new int[dimensions[0], dimensions[1]];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game_Of_Life gol = new Game_Of_Life();

            // Runs two generations of Game of Life
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                gol.Print();
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
        }

        void Print()
        {
            string prettyPrint = "";
            int[,] currentBoard = CalculateBoard();

            // Used to format the board to be suitable for printing to console.
            // Not in final state, only setup this way for debugging the current issues.
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; j++)
                {
                    prettyPrint += currentBoard[i, j].ToString();
                }
                prettyPrint += "\n";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(prettyPrint);
            oldBoard = newBoard;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
        int[,] CalculateBoard()
        {
            // These loops run every cell in the array through the alive() function 
            // and returns the board for the next generation.
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; j++)
                {
                    newBoard[i, j] = Alive(j, i);
                }
            }
            return newBoard;
        }

        int Alive(int x, int y)
        {
            int temp = 0;

            // These two nested four loops *should* check the surrounding 8 squares for any alive cells, 
            // treating any outside the array as dead 
            // and returns a 1 if the cell is alive, or 0 if it's dead

            for (int ia = -1; ia <= 1; ia++)
            {
                for (int ja = -1; ja <= 1; ja++)
                {
                    if (ia == 0 && ja == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        temp += oldBoard[y + ia, x + ja];
                    }

                    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                    {
                        temp += 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Lives if 2 or 3 alive neighbours
            if (temp == 2 && oldBoard[y, x] == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Alive (2) " + temp + " " + oldBoard[y, x]);
                return 1;
            }

            // Born if 3 exact neighbours
            else if (temp == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Alive (3) " + temp);
                return 1;
            }

            // Anything else, cell dies
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dead " + temp + " " + oldBoard[y, x]);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any further feedback or suggestions are also welcome. I'm always looking to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is this: `oldBoard = newBoard;`. Since arrays are passed by reference, this means the old board and the new board will reference the *same* array. And this will cause obvious problems.

you could probably solve this by switching the references to ensure that the new and old always refer to different objects.

```
(oldBoard, newBoard) = (newBoard, oldBoard);
```

I would also recommend reading Eric Lipperts series on [Game Of Life](https://ericlippert.com/2020/04/13/life-part-1/). This covers the subject in about as much details as you could possibly hope for.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems to have fixed the issue and I can see why I was getting those results now. I just assumed it would copy the values from one array into the other rather than set it as a reference.